# How to generate a heteroskedastic model in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I am looking to create heteroskedastic data in Python using Numpy.

```
bias=100
N=10
X = np.arange(1,N,0.2).reshape(-1,1)
y_true = np.ravel(X.dot(0.3) + bias)
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (N-1)*5)
y = y_true + noise
```

I need each element in noise come from a normal distribution with a different variance for heteroskedasticity. Ideally the variances must be a function of the corresponding value of X. How to ensure this? np.random.normal accepts only scalar variance terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `help(np.random.normal)`:

> **normal**(...) method of mtrand.RandomState instance
>      normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
>      ...
>   scale : float or **array_like of floats**
>      Standard deviation (spread or "width") of the distribution.

So, `np.random.normal` accepts an array of variance terms, if you need it. Here's an example of ten random samples with the same mean 0 and progressively increasing standard deviation:

```
np.random.normal(scale=np.arange(1,10))
#array([ -0.04997945,   2.05945125,   1.07041091,   7.2321691 ,
#        -2.31088503,   9.20914924,  -3.1213077 ,  -3.87994062,
#       -19.3611583 ])
```

Here's a 2D array of 10000 samples from each distribution and their standard deviations:

```
np.stack([np.random.normal(scale=np.arange(1,10)) 
          for x in range(10000)]).std(axis=0)
#array([1.01413654, 2.01043535, 2.97448904, 3.98098459, 5.045089  ,
#       5.95467152, 6.94379633, 8.01227677, 9.0252082 ])
```

Comment: I think that array is for drawing samples from multivariate Gaussian and not multiple 1D samples each with different variances.

Comment: Well, that's not true. See the example in the updated answer.